# Unable to connect Express app with Flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, express

I am trying to store user data from flutter in Mongodb using Nodejs and Express. I made a rest api which will store data in MongoDb locally but the data is not getting stored. Here is the code of the rest Api.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

let database;

async function initDb() {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');
    database = client.db('project');
}

function getDb() {
    if(!database) {
        throw new Error('Database not connected');
    }
    return database;
}

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/data', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    getDb().collection('userData').insertOne(req.body);
    console.log('Data submited');
    res.json('Data submited');
});

initDb().then(function() {
    app.listen(3000, console.log('Listining to port 3000'));
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Connecting to the database failed');  
});
```

Here is the flutter code in which I am calling the Api.

```
class StoreUserData {
  postData() async {
    print('Function Called');
    try {
      var response = http.post(
        Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:3000/data'),
        body: {
          'username': user!.displayName,
          'email': user!.email,
          'uid': user!.uid
        },
      );
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Change the URI in flutter to `http://localhost:3000/data`

Comment: try post man and see if you can reach your API, then try to use it in your flutter app.btw you're express code is weird , you don't need to run the initDB first,just run the app without any dependency